# Why the universe of neural network is a ring K?

Tags: ring-theory, real-numbers

I wish to find an algebraic or category theory approach to describe neural network in particular to have use algebraic method to extract the concept of 'synaptic weight'. 
I find this for the moment, [pag 4-5](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3de6/d2dd204958731f0d3eeccdc317547b5a9413.pdf)

**Definition 1** The universe of a neural network is a
set that contains all of the possible values in a neural
network. The universe of neural network is a **ring K**.

**Remark 1** We have not defined what the ring K is.
Basically, the universe of a neural network is a set
that enables the operation between the components
with some properties such as closure. Normally the
universe of a neural network is a ***set of real numbers***.

Instead, in standard definition we have a bad approach

> synaptic weight is *amplitude* of a connection between two nodes
>   The amplitude of a periodic variable is a measure of its change over a single period

I don't like this poor description in terms of physical or biological terms, I don't like terms 'amplitude', 'neuron' or 'synaptic weights', I prefer something like this

> In a computational neural network, a vector or set of inputs x and outputs y, or pre- and post-synaptic neurons respectively, are interconnected with synaptic weights represented by the matrix w, where for a linear neuron

But I don't like term '**output**' because this carry a perception of some 'signal' but in mathematical terms what can be this 'output'?

Comment: Aren't the outputs vectors just as the inputs are?  I do not know what you are trying to ask. It sounds like you are fishing for someone to give you a term you like, and that is not really a mathematical question.

Comment: Also, the final question seems to diverge a lot from your original question.  It really seems like you'd be working with $\mathbb R$ or possibly $\mathbb C$ in some special case. I don't imagine anyone has done any neural network stuff with weirder rings.  $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ carry the brunt of applications.

Comment: "Why the universe of neural network is a ring K?" because you need to add, subtract and multiply those measurements, and sometimes even divide by them.  How could you do any computation otherwise??